# How can I convert float to int?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
cube1.name = string.Format("Terrain_{0}_{1}", 
    (int)Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.x + tilePositionInLocalSpace.x, 
    (int)Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.z + tilePositionInLocalSpace.y);
```

Tried to cast it for `int` but it didn't change much.
The name of each cube is still for example: `Terrain_6.5_5.5`. But I want the name to be `Terrain_6_5`.

`tilePositionInLocalSpace` is `vector3` type and both `x` are `float` type.

Comment: Add brackets: (int)(Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.x + tilePositionInLocalSpace.x).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've just got a precedence problem. You've got:

```
(int) x + y
```

which is equivalent to

```
((int) x) + y
```

... which will then promote the result of the cast back to a float in order to perform floating point addition. Just make the cast apply to the whole result instead:

```
(int) (x + y)
```

Where `x` and `y` are the rather long expressions in your original code, of course. For the sake of readability, I'd extract the two values to separate local variables, so you'd have:

```
int sumX = (int) (Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.x + tilePositionInLocalSpace.x);
int sumY = (int) (Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.z + tilePositionInLocalSpace.y);
cube1.name = string.Format("Terrain_{0}_{1}", sumX, sumY);
```

Or better still:

```
var position = Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position;
int sumX = (int) (position.x + tilePositionInLocalSpace.x);
int sumY = (int) (position.z + tilePositionInLocalSpace.y);
cube1.name = string.Format("Terrain_{0}_{1}", sumX, sumY);
```

Comment: One step back. Why not let the formatting do it's work? Thats the whole trick of formatting.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: I'd say that's less obvious in terms of effect than the casting, personally.

Answer (score 2):

you need to cast both as `int` since now you are adding an `int` with a `float` which of course results to  `float`. Try:

```
cube1.name = string.Format("Terrain_{0}_{1}", (int)(Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.x + tilePositionInLocalSpace.x), (int)(Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.z + tilePositionInLocalSpace.y))
```

Comment: Casting both is a bad idea - that will lose more information than it needs to, compared with casting *the whole result* to int.

Comment: Correct. Bad explanation. I wanted to say to cast the addition

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the result of the addition:

```
(int) (x + y);
```

And then string.format ()...

Answer (score 1):

I would just specify the number of digits on the formatting. It can be done by entering a format.

Like this:

```
// here                                |     |  
cube1.name = string.Format("Terrain_{0:0}_{1:0}", 
    Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.x + tilePositionInLocalSpace.x, 
    Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.z + tilePositionInLocalSpace.y);
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to explicitly convert it:

```
cube1.name = string.Format("Terrain_{0}_{1}",
Convert.ToInt32(Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.x + tilePositionInLocalSpace.x),
Convert.ToInt32(Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position.z + tilePositionInLocalSpace.y));
```

Comment: This is simply false.  `Convert.ToInt32` is simply a less efficient way of converting a `float` to an `int`.  The purpose of `Convert.*` is for converting *a value where you do not know it's type*, but know that it's `IConvertible`, and that's simply not the case here.  Using the cast operator *is* converting it, as there is an explicit conversion operator from `float` to `int`.